# Google oAuth - validate user in JS, but use in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth

We have a web application that needs to synchronize scheduled events with a user's Google calendar.  A Windows service will add/edit/delete Google calendar events for the user.

We are considering...

1. In our web app we authenticate the user with the Google oAuth2 JS libraries
2. Collect a token once the user has allowed our app to work with their calendar
3. Save that token server side, so a Windows service can then update the user's calendar.

Is this workable?  Also, how do we renew expired tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article explains how to do it.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

**TL;DR**

[image]